# My Header Banner in HTML 5 and CSS isn' working

Tags: css, html

I've got some trouble with my code. At the moment I'm working with HTML and CSS and got some problems with my header-banner-picture. It isn't responsive and I don't know why.

```
hmtl
<header id="header-banner"></header>

css
#header-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 20.83%;
    background:url("../img/header.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

I'm also open for a JavaScript solution, but I really don't know why it's not working.

I' looking forward to hearing from you,

Fred

Comment: because it have set `height: 0;` probably :)

Comment: What do you mean, it isn't repsonsive? Can you explain the behavior you would expect but can't get to work?

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
   <header id="header-banner"></header>
     <style>
        #header-banner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-top: 20.83%;
        background: url("../img/header.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
      }
   </style>
</html>
```

Comment: consider adding explanation around